# Get OMR code into a pdf file using PHP

Tags: php, printing, fpdf

We have a enveloping machine that is able to read optical character recognition codes (OMR). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition
For that we want enrich our PDF output with such an OMR code. We use FPDF in PHP to generate our documents.
Is there a way to greate these codes maybe as a picture?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I assume you mean Optical Mark Recognition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could insert images into your PDF that your OMR enveloping machine could read.

If so, I can recommend this FPDF Script which writes out standard HTML which can include images into the PDF being created:

http://fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php

```
$pdf->WriteHTML("<img src="http://www.example.com/OMR_readable_image.gif">");
```

If you need to dynamically create images with page numbers, I can see a solution where you combine a circle background image with the page number text to create an image that you then use as your image source.

How to create an image dynamically:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php

Comment: Yes, that could be a workaround but a dynamic solution which can work with all number of pages would be better ;)

Comment: I updated my answer with info on dynamically creating images.  Perhaps that will solve your issue.